# Forms Authentication: page access based on user's category

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, web-config

I have two pages: `Members.aspx` and `Admins.aspx`. I want to make unlogged users to see none of them, any logged user to see the first one and only certain users to see both.

User's category ("member" or "admin") is detected at login time from the code and is put in a session variable.

I can easily grant access to any logged user to some page using Forms Authentication (basically as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), but how should I design my `web.config` in order to take in account not the username but his category?

Note that users could anytime change their category so i can't hard-code their names, and I need this to be db-independent so I shall stick to Forms Authentication login mode.

Comment: You can only use web.config if your category == Membership.Role. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should look into

[Asp.net roles management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And

[Filtering Site-Map Nodes Based on Security Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178429%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

It would be smarter than trying to build your own security mechanism based upon Session values.

Comment: Thank you, I'd like to use roles indeed as it seems the most solid solution but my main trouble is understanding how to assign roles on the fly at login time.

Comment: `Roles.AddUserToRole("JoeWorden", "manager");` Follow the first link for full information on it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Role-based authentication. A user can have one or more roles. .NET has classes to help you manage users along with their roles.

This is one good tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043732/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082703-1.aspx

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your pages in folders grouped by roles, and create a Web.config for each folder:

For your Admin zone you can use:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow roles="admin"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And for your Member zone you can use:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow roles="admin"/>
         <allow roles="member"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In the second block, the three elements can be replaced by `<deny users="?" />`.